Problem with setInterval to change number
I have a problem with following Code:
"use strict";

//Get Elements with Classes
let clock_hours_big = document.getElementsByClassName("clock__hours-big")[0];
let clock_hours_low = document.getElementsByClassName("clock__hours-low")[0];
let clock_seconds_big = document.getElementsByClassName("clock__seconds-big")[0];
let clock_seconds_low = document.getElementsByClassName("clock__seconds-low")[0];

//create Variables
let firstNumber = 0;
let secondNumber = 0;
let thirdNumber = 0;
let fourthNumber = 0;
let headline = "h1";

//change time of clock in function
let showNumbers = function(selectQuery, selectPosition, selectNumber) {
    let Position = selectPosition.querySelector(selectQuery);
    Position.textContent = parseInt(selectNumber);
}
let changeNumbers = function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        firstNumber = firstNumber + 1;
    },1000)
}

showNumbers(headline,clock_hours_big, firstNumber);
showNumbers(headline,clock_hours_low, secondNumber);
showNumbers(headline,clock_seconds_big, thirdNumber);
showNumbers(headline,clock_seconds_low, fourthNumber);
changeNumbers();

i like to develop a timer, but my function "changeNumbers()" dont work and i dont know why. In this function i like to change the number of the variable "firstNumber" and then i like to show it in other function, which is called "showNumbers". Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Your interval function changes one variable, but it does not update the HTML on the page.  Add the code to update the HTML into the interval function.  (1) Set initial variables  (2) in the interval function, (a) update the variables -and- (b) update the page using the current values.

@DaveS no, my Interval does not change my number, i already checked it, with console.log

The problem is that you only call your showNumbers() functions once, when you really need to be calling them every time your timer goes off to update the display.
I moved the four calls into one function and called that one function from inside your timer function. See the NOTE comments in the runnable code snippet for the changes.


//Get Elements with Classes
let clock_hours_big = document.getElementsByClassName("clock__hours-big")[0];
let clock_hours_low = document.getElementsByClassName("clock__hours-low")[0];
let clock_seconds_big = document.getElementsByClassName("clock__seconds-big")[0];
let clock_seconds_low = document.getElementsByClassName("clock__seconds-low")[0];

//create Variables
let firstNumber = 0;
let secondNumber = 0;
let thirdNumber = 0;
let fourthNumber = 0;
let headline = "h1";

//change time of clock in function
let showNumbers = function(selectQuery, selectPosition, selectNumber) {
    let Position = selectPosition.querySelector(selectQuery);
    Position.textContent = parseInt(selectNumber);
}
let changeNumbers = function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        firstNumber = firstNumber + 1;

        // NOTE For testing purposes
        secondNumber += 10;
        thirdNumber += 100;
        fourthNumber += 1000;

        // NOTE call the showNumbers() functions every time you change the numbers 
        showAllNumbers( )
    },1000)
}

function showAllNumbers( ) {
  // NOTE Move all these calls into a function, so we can call this function from your setInterval function
  showNumbers(headline,clock_hours_big, firstNumber);
  showNumbers(headline,clock_hours_low, secondNumber);
  showNumbers(headline,clock_seconds_big, thirdNumber);
  showNumbers(headline,clock_seconds_low, fourthNumber);
}

changeNumbers();
h1 {
  height: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid maroon;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
<div class="clock__hours-big"> <h1></h1> </div>
<div class="clock__hours-low"> <h1></h1> </div>
<div class="clock__seconds-big"> <h1></h1> </div>
<div class="clock__seconds-low"> <h1></h1> </div>



